# How to fix "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}"

Tags: php

I'm working with if statements, and I cannot seem to find where I'm going wrong, I'm fairly new to PHP so If someone can maybe guide me in the right direction it would be awesome, thanks.

I've tried to rewrite the whole code, and experimented by adding more "}" on the end of the code, which did not seem to work at all.

```php
<?php
$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();

    //Connect to the database
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

    //If the register button is clicked
    if (isset($_POST['register'])){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password_1']);
        $password_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password_2']);
        //Ensure that the form fields are filled correctly.
        if (empty($username)){
            array_push($errors, "A username is required.")}
        if (empty($email)){
            array_push($errors, "An email is required.")}
        if (empty($password_1 != $password_2)){
            array_push($errors, "Passwords do not match.")}
        }
```

Comment: you missed semicolon end of every array_push line

Comment: What a silly mistake, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed semicolon,at the end of array_push line

```
if (empty($username)){
    array_push($errors, "A username is required.");
}
if (empty($email)){
   array_push($errors, "An email is required.");
}
if (empty($password_1 != $password_2)){
    array_push($errors, "Passwords do not match.");
}
```